# How to remove this CA in product price magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

[image]

How to remove this CA in product price?

Comment: in Stores -> Currency Symbol Check With Symbol You Put ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, then follow below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Please add details to your answer so that it can be more helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Go To `Stores -> Currency Symbols`

[image]

**Remove CA And Save Currency**